# Proof of MM implies non-stationary ideal on $\aleph_1$ is $\aleph_2$ saturated.

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I am trying to understand the proof of thm 37.16 of Jech on page 687.
I don't understand the first 4 lines, why does that suffice to proof the theorem? I don't see how they are related. It sais the following:

Assume MM and let $\{A_i : i \in W \} $ be a maximal almost disjoint collection of stationary subsets of $\omega_1$. We shall find a set $Z\subset W$ of size $\leq \aleph_1$ such that $\sum_{i\in Z} A_i$ contains a closed unbounded set. This implies the theorem.

Here the sum is the diagonal union. In the comments it was suggested that almost disjoint in this case means two different $A_i$'s have a non-stationary intersection.

Thanks!

Comment: Since not everyone memorized Jech's 700+ pages book by heart, it is a good idea to at least properly state the theorem and the parts which are unclear. It is not plagiarism if this is for educational purposes, which it is.

Comment: Fair enough! There is Jech online ofcourse, but you are right.

Comment: When asking random strangers online for help, one shouldn't have them bother to go to various lengths in order to understand the question you're *really* asking.

Comment: I think that almost disjoint here means that the intersection is non-stationary, especially if the sum is the diagonal union.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, Good to know my guess for the almost disjointness was false. will edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider the Boolean algebra $\Bbb B=\mathcal P(\omega_1)/\rm NS$ (one can also just consider this as a notion of forcing). Saturation simply means that it has the $\aleph_2$-chain condition.

So take a maximal family of mutually stationary sets, which is exactly a maximal antichain in $\Bbb B$. If there is a family of size $\aleph_1$ whose union contains a club, that means that this family would already constitute a partition of $1_{\Bbb B}$ (in forcing terms: this family would induce a maxiaml antichain already), because $1_{\Bbb B}$ is exactly the club filter on $\omega_1$.

In other words, it means that every maximal antichain in $\Bbb B$ is of size $<\aleph_2$, which is exactly what we want to prove.

Comment: So.. Unfortunatly I am not yet familiar with Boolean algebra's. I don't understand what is going on.

Though, I was planning to have a closer look at it anyway, which means I will probably understand it some point in the future. 

A more elementary proof would be great as well.

Comment: Well. You were reading in Jech, so I figured you at least know the basics, because Jech is doing almost everything he can in terms of Boolean algebras. Specifically, forcing (and MM is a *forcing* axiom...).

Comment: Do you know anything about forcing?

Comment: Yes, I did quite a bit of forcing. Including product forcing, iterated forcing... Though never learned that via Jech/the boolen algebra way.

Comment: Well. Think about this just in terms of forcing. Where a maximal antichain is an antichain whose only supremum is $1$, the maximum condition.

Comment: I am trying to understand it, though there are just too many terms in there with which I am still unfamiliar.

So the idea is to translate this problem to the language of Boolean Algebra's, and then it seems to be true by rather obvious reasons. So maximal almost disjoint collection of stationary subsets is becoming this maximal family of mutually stationary sets, right?

Comment: In forcing terms an antichain is maximal if and only if the only condition weaker than *all* the members of the antichain is the maximum, $1$. Here this means that an antichain is maximal, if the diagonal union contains a club.

Comment: Yes. I used "mutually stationary" because it might be clearer than "almost disjoint" which would have multiple meanings in different contexts.

Comment: So for now, I just need to dive into this notions of Boolean algebra to understand what is going on. Hopefully, in some time it will all make sense and be easy. :) 
Thanks!

Comment: These are useful notions to learn. Good luck.